# Rails - If in admin namespace: skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is the above possible?

I need to run `skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include` but only if the request is in the admin namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, in `application_controller.rb`.

`skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include, if: -> { self.class.parent == Admin }`

This will only work if all the controllers in the Admin namespace inherit from ApplicationController. like this `class Admin::FooController < ApplicationController`.

That said I would use Refactoring. This blog post has a good example in a Rails 4 application. http://blog.roberteshleman.com/2014/08/14/using-rails-namespaces-for-admin-actions/

Comment: Thanks that put me onto the right line, my admin controllers were not inheriting from application controller. I found which one they were using and decorated that. Using the spree gem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AdminController` that inherits from `ApplicationController` and put your `skip_after_action` there.

Then:

`Admin::FooController < AdminController`

rather than

`Admin::FooController < ApplicationController`